# HTML/JS Uncaught ReferenceError

Tags: javascript, html

I am using bootstrap to style my button in HTML file by:

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Start</button>
```

And I want to access the class in js file by

```js
var buttonStart = document.getElementsByClassName('btn btn-primary');
```

And I got the error in the console. Is there any problem with my code?

```
VM131:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: buttonStart is not defined at <anonymous>:1:1
```

```html
        <p><span id="seconds">00</span>:<span id="tens">00</span></p>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Start</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Stop</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Reset</button>
```

```js
window.onload = function(){
    var seconds = 00;
    var tens = 00;
    var appendTens = document.getElementById("tens");
    var appendSeconds = document.getElementById("seconds");
    var buttonStart = document.getElementsByClassName('btn btn-primary');
    var buttonStop = document.getElementsByClassName("btn btn-secondary");
    var buttonReset = document.getElementsByClassName("btn btn-secondary");
    var interval;

    buttonStart.onclick = function(){

        clearInterval(interval);
        interval = setInterval(startTimer, 10);
    }
    buttonStop.onclick = function() {
        clearInterval(interval);
    }


   buttonReset.onclick = function() {
      clearInterval(interval);
     tens = "00";
       seconds = "00";
     appendTens.innerHTML = tens;
       appendSeconds.innerHTML = seconds;
   }

   function startTimer () {
    tens++; 

    if(tens < 9){
      appendTens.innerHTML = "0" + tens;
    }

    if (tens > 9){
      appendTens.innerHTML = tens;

    } 

    if (tens > 99) {
      console.log("seconds");
      seconds++;
      appendSeconds.innerHTML = "0" + seconds;
      tens = 0;
      appendTens.innerHTML = "0" + 0;
    }

    if (seconds > 9){
      appendSeconds.innerHTML = seconds;
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: At first, I used different id for different buttons (start, stop, reset) and .getElementById() and the program works perfectly

Comment: Are you using `buttonStart` anywhere else in the code too, which you haven't shown?

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava That's all the code I have

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava it works when I use different id for different buttons(start, stop, reset). However, when I tried to use bootstrap by changing from id to class, it is not working

Comment: Most likely you're loading the script in the `<head>` before the content located in the `<body>` loads. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436411/where-should-i-put-script-tags-in-html-markup) for details.

Comment: @JuanMarco I put the script before the closing body tag

Comment: `getElementsByClassName()` returns an HTMLCollection, you can't attach events directly to it. You will need to loop through and attach them individually.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What do querySelectorAll and getElementsBy\* methods return?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-do-queryselectorall-and-getelementsby-methods-return)

Comment: `var buttonStart = document.getElementsByClassName('btn btn-primary')[0]` @HereticMonkey Thank you! .getElementsByClassName() will return an array

Comment: But can anyone explain why OP gets `Uncaught ReferenceError: buttonStart is not defined at ...` instead of say `buttonStart.onclick is not a function`? Why is it not defined?

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava it should not event throw an error.

Comment: @epascarello So agreed that the behavior is not correct?

Answer (score 1):

The main issue is that you're capturing the `<button>` elements using [`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName). This method returns a [`HTML Collection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) which behaves like an array (technically an array like object). So, to fix this you would need to reference the first element of that collection:

```
var buttonStart = document.getElementsByClassName('btn btn-primary')[0]
```

Working example below:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var seconds = 00;
  var tens = 00;
  var appendTens = document.getElementById("tens");
  var appendSeconds = document.getElementById("seconds");
  var buttonStart = document.getElementsByClassName('btn btn-primary')[0];
  var buttonStop = document.getElementsByClassName("btn btn-secondary")[0];
  var buttonReset = document.getElementsByClassName("btn btn-tertiary")[0];
  var interval;

  buttonStart.onclick = function() {

    clearInterval(interval);
    interval = setInterval(startTimer, 10);
  }
  buttonStop.onclick = function() {
    clearInterval(interval);
  }


  buttonReset.onclick = function() {
    clearInterval(interval);
    tens = "00";
    seconds = "00";
    appendTens.innerHTML = tens;
    appendSeconds.innerHTML = seconds;
  }

  function startTimer() {
    tens++;

    if (tens < 9) {
      appendTens.innerHTML = "0" + tens;
    }

    if (tens > 9) {
      appendTens.innerHTML = tens;

    }

    if (tens > 99) {
      console.log("seconds");
      seconds++;
      appendSeconds.innerHTML = "0" + seconds;
      tens = 0;
      appendTens.innerHTML = "0" + 0;
    }

    if (seconds > 9) {
      appendSeconds.innerHTML = seconds;
    }

  }
}
```

```html
<p><span id="seconds">00</span>:<span id="tens">00</span></p>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Start</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Stop</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-tertiary">Reset</button>
```

It's probably a better idea to use an ID along with [`getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) or if you want to keep using those classes you can use [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector) which will return the first element that matches that specific class.

**Note**: I modified the third class to be `btn-tertiary` so the example could work.

Comment: Well explained answer and my sentiment exactly.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add 3 even listeners and define your functions correctly, the code is fine.

```js
     
window.onload = function(){
    var seconds = 00;
    var tens = 00;
    var appendTens = document.getElementById("tens");
    var appendSeconds = document.getElementById("seconds");
    var buttonStart = document.getElementsByClassName('btn btn-primary')[0];
    var buttonStop = document.getElementsByClassName("btn btn-secondary")[0];
    var buttonReset = document.getElementsByClassName("btn btn-secondary")[1];
    var interval;

    buttonStart.addEventListener("click", start);

    function start() {        
        clearInterval(interval);
        interval = setInterval(startTimer, 10);
    }
    buttonStop.addEventListener("click", stop);
  function stop() {
        clearInterval(interval);
    }


   buttonReset.addEventListener("click", restart);
  function restart() {
      clearInterval(interval);
     tens = "00";
       seconds = "00";
     appendTens.innerHTML = tens;
       appendSeconds.innerHTML = seconds;
   }

   function startTimer () {
    tens++; 

    if(tens < 9){
      appendTens.innerHTML = "0" + tens;
    }

    if (tens > 9){
      appendTens.innerHTML = tens;

    } 

    if (tens > 99) {
      console.log("seconds");
      seconds++;
      appendSeconds.innerHTML = "0" + seconds;
      tens = 0;
      appendTens.innerHTML = "0" + 0;
    }

    if (seconds > 9){
      appendSeconds.innerHTML = seconds;
    }

  }
}
```

```html
     <p><span id="seconds">00</span>:<span id="tens">00</span></p>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Start</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Stop</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Reset</button>
```

Comment: Planning on adding an explanation, or just leave the code dump and expect us to play spot-the-difference?

Comment: it's pretty obvious isn't it?

Comment: what's not obvious is how this isn't a duplicate of any other question about `getElementsByClassName` returning an HTMLCollection...

Comment: `var buttonStart = document.getElementsByClassName('btn btn-primary')[0]`

Comment: This answer defeats the purpose of using`getElementsByClassName()`, better off using `querySelector()`. OP obviously needs an event for several elements.

Comment: you all make excellent points.  please feel free to add a better answer